# Ruby Sinatra: show clickable list of files

Tags: ruby, sinatra

i have this simple script to show all files in a folder, it works in the console but gives a different result in Sinatra (with path and extension). Why is this so, and how can i best present these basenames (without path and extension) in a ul list as a link to open this file in the browser using Sinatra ?
The goal is to present a clickable list of pages to open if no filename is given. I allready have the routine to show the files.

console:

```
require 'find'

def get_files path
 dir_array = Array.new
 Find.find(path) do |f|
    dir_array << f if !File.directory?(f) # add only non-directories  
 end
 return dir_array
end  

for filename in get_files 'c:/sinatra_wiki/views'
  basename = File.basename(filename, ".*")
  puts basename
end

=> index
   index2
```

Sinatra:

```
require 'find'

def get_files path
 dir_array = Array.new
 Find.find(path) do |f|
    dir_array << f if !File.directory?(f) # add only non-directories  
 end
 return dir_array
end  

get '/' do
  for filename in get_files 'c:/sinatra_wiki/views'
    basename = File.basename(filename, ".*")
    puts basename
  end
end
=> c:/sinatra_wiki/views/index.htmlc:/sinatra_wiki/views/index2.erb
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your sinatra implementation, the result you see in the browser is not the one from the `puts basename` statement in the `get` block. It's the return value of the `get_files` method.  Try adding `puts "<p>#{base name}</p>"` instead of the `puts basename` in the `get` block and see for yourself.

Some changes:

The `get_files` method: Instead of sending the entire file path, send only the file name

```
dir_array << File.basename(f, ".*")
```

Add a view in case you need clarity:

```
get '/' do
   @arr = get_files(the_path)
   erb :index
end
```

elsewhere, in the app/views folder, in an index.erb file:

```
<h2>Page list</h2>

<ul> 
  <% @arr.each do |page| %>
    <li><a href="/<%=page%>"><%=page> %></a></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

This is to list out the file names in a similar way to that of the console output.

TL;DR: Put the looping part in the view!

Comment: thanks Kashyap but now i get only an empty ul in the browser and i get no errors. how can i see what the contents of @arr is in the index.erb ? can i send output to the console too ?

Comment: Well, what was the mistake? It would help me :)

Comment: did't keep the original, the mix of markup and code was not right, sure it is not optimal but it works, i come from ASP and there much mangling of the two is discouraged, initially yours was prettier but didn't give result

Comment: And you might want to use `pry` as a debugging tool. It lets you see the contents of @arr in the console.

`require 'pry'`

use `binding.pry` anywhere in your application to let it yield control to the console whenever the application encounters that statement.

Comment: tried pry with a few examples but i get errors in win32console-1.3.1-x86-mingw32 8<(